# Switch from Pyenv to Conda

Tags: pip, conda, pyenv

I've been using pyenv but I want to switch to Conda. I use VScode, managed to create a Conda environment and use the proper version of Python but when installing packages with PIP, they still install on pyenv and not conda, how do I change that? Should I just remove pyenv from my computer or can I just change the path for pip?

Not sure if that'll help but I did an echo $PATH and got this list
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/condabin:/Users/marc/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 0):

Marc, it is not clear from your question whether you've configured conda correctly for VS Code, which means

1. setting the default terminal
2. ensuring the default terminal [is correctly reading ~/.profile args](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67843008/7103117)
3. ensuring you can [select your miniforge conda env](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) from list of python interpreters.

More details about ensuring conda is configured properly is in this [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072121/7103117).

Finally, please ensure that you pip install inside the activated conda env? This is obvious.... for sanity sake ensure you can see the env activated at the shell prompt inside your VSCode terminal before doing pip / conda install commands. Running `which pip` at the prompt should confirm that you are using pip inside the miniforge path.